Postfix Mail being redirected to private inbox
I am relatively new to Linux, setting up servers and especially handling mail related things. I've bought a new domain and rented a VPS, which now hosts my website. I need a more open environment for my webproject, including generating email-addresses automatically and reading their inboxes. This is why I couldn't use a normal webhosting package.
Long story short I am a total beginner and got stuck on a problem while setting up postfix, for which I couldn't find any solutions online. I've got to the point, where the webserver runs with a valid certificate and the same domain name as my webserver. Means, requesting https://example.com works and messaging contact@example.com works.
Sounds good so far. My problem is, that any mail sent to any inbox automatically gets redirected to my private mail.
This means the following, let's say someone sends an email to contact@mydomain.com. Instead of me being able to view this mail using s-nail, the mail gets forwarded to my private address.
someone@mail.com -> contact@mydomain.com -> ??? -> myprivatemail@proton.me
I have probably made a mistake whilst setting up postfix. I thought I might have set the wrong value for "Root and postmaster mail recipient".
For this reason I tried reconfiguring postfix using sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix and restarting the service using sudo systemctl restart postfix. This didn't change anything.
Logs:
Jun 28 13:40:44 srv552577 postfix/postfix-script[61682]: waiting for the Postfix mail system to terminate
Jun 28 13:40:45 srv552577 postfix/postfix-script[61994]: starting the Postfix mail system
Jun 28 13:40:45 srv552577 postfix/master[61996]: daemon started -- version 3.8.6, configuration /etc/postfix
Jun 28 13:42:16 srv552577 postfix/smtpd[62024]: warning: database /etc/postfix/virtual.db is older than source file /etc/postfix/virtual
Jun 28 13:42:16 srv552577 postfix/smtpd[62024]: connect from mail-yb1-f179.google.com[209.85.219.179]
Jun 28 13:42:17 srv552577 postfix/trivial-rewrite[62028]: warning: database /etc/postfix/virtual.db is older than source file /etc/postfix/virtual
Jun 28 13:42:17 srv552577 postfix/cleanup[62029]: warning: database /etc/postfix/virtual.db is older than source file /etc/postfix/virtual
Jun 28 13:42:17 srv552577 postfix/smtpd[62024]: 56BFF40D79: client=mail-yb1-f179.google.com[209.85.219.179]
Jun 28 13:42:17 srv552577 postfix/cleanup[62029]: 56BFF40D79: message-id=<CAF41jLugJXH2jx6K8X+wh01Fb7-ru_mTO_Nyqf8ALEwg_y1vQA@mail.gmail.com>
Jun 28 13:42:17 srv552577 postfix/qmgr[61998]: 56BFF40D79: from=<myclearname@gmail.com>, size=2827, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 28 13:42:17 srv552577 postfix/cleanup[62029]: 5A00740D7B: message-id=<CAF41jLugJXH2jx6K8X+wh01Fb7-ru_mTO_Nyqf8ALEwg_y1vQA@mail.gmail.com>
Jun 28 13:42:17 srv552577 postfix/local[62030]: 56BFF40D79: to=<root@unlockedmail.de>, orig_to=<admin@unlockedmail.de>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as 5A00740D7B)
Jun 28 13:42:17 srv552577 postfix/qmgr[61998]: 5A00740D7B: from=<myclearname@gmail.com>, size=2964, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 28 13:42:17 srv552577 postfix/qmgr[61998]: 56BFF40D79: removed
Jun 28 13:42:17 srv552577 postfix/smtpd[62024]: disconnect from mail-yb1-f179.google.com[209.85.219.179] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 bdat=1 quit=1 commands=7
Jun 28 13:42:24 srv552577 postfix/smtp[62031]: 5A00740D7B: to=<brentspine@proton.me>, orig_to=<admin@unlockedmail.de>, relay=mail.protonmail.ch[176.119.200.128]:25, delay=6.9, delays=0/0.02/5.9/1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: q>
Jun 28 13:42:24 srv552577 postfix/qmgr[61998]: 5A00740D7B: removed
Jun 28 13:45:37 srv552577 postfix/anvil[62027]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:209.85.219.179) at Jun 28 13:42:16
Jun 28 13:45:37 srv552577 postfix/anvil[62027]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:209.85.219.179) at Jun 28 13:42:16
Jun 28 13:45:37 srv552577 postfix/anvil[62027]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Jun 28 13:42:16

/etc/postfix/virtual:
contact@mydomain.com brent
admin@mydomain.com brent

/etc/postfix/main.cf:
  GNU nano 7.2                                                                                                       main.cf *
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 3.6 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 3.6



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = srv552577.hstgr.cloud
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = srv552577.hstgr.cloud, IREPLACEDTHISDOMAIN.de, srv552577.hstgr.cloud, localhost.hstgr.cloud, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

/etc/postfix/master.cf:
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
# Choose one: enable submission for loopback clients only, or for any client.
#127.0.0.1:submission inet n -   y       -       -       smtpd
#submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
#  -o local_header_rewrite_clients=static:all
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#     Instead of specifying complex smtpd_<xxx>_restrictions here,
#     specify "smtpd_<xxx>_restrictions=$mua_<xxx>_restrictions"
#     here, and specify mua_<xxx>_restrictions in main.cf (where
#     "<xxx>" is "client", "helo", "sender", "relay", or "recipient").
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
# Choose one: enable submissions for loopback clients only, or for any client.
#127.0.0.1:submissions inet n  -       y       -       -       smtpd
#submissions     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submissions
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o local_header_rewrite_clients=static:all
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#     Instead of specifying complex smtpd_<xxx>_restrictions here,
#     specify "smtpd_<xxx>_restrictions=$mua_<xxx>_restrictions"
#     here, and specify mua_<xxx>_restrictions in main.cf (where
#     "<xxx>" is "client", "helo", "sender", "relay", or "recipient").
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr

My TXT and MX DNS records:

Let me know what I can do to fix this or if I should supply you with any other information.
Thanks in Advance

Is your MX record set correctly? Do you see that mail is being accepted by your server in the server logs?

Hey, thanks for your answer. I updated my post accordingly. I was told to set the MX record to mail.mydomain.com, now that I think about it. Is that correct? I was not questioning it, since everything with sending and forwarding mails works

I am still figuring things out, so I don't know how to access the postfix logs right now to be honest. I'll update the post if I figured it out haha @C-nan

Tell us the real domain. Hiding it makes helping you more complicated.

You can switch out mydomain.com for any site. It's https://unlockedmail.de

Do you have TLS certs to match your hostname?

Your MX record points to 185.224.139.xx, is that your server? You can view the logs in /var/log/mail.log or /var/log/maillog depending on your distro.

Yes, that is my server, "185.224.139.41" to be exact. I didn't have the time yesterday, but I enabled logging now. Should've done that earlier... I updated my post accordingly, but I'll also have a look at it myself now that I have these infos

It looks like the problem was due to not updating the Postfix virtual alias database after editing the /etc/postfix/virtual file. I didn't know, that this step was crucial to apply changes made.
Here's what I did to fix my issue:
Updated the virtual alias database:
After making changes to the /etc/postfix/virtual file, you need to run the following command:
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual

This updates the file /etc/postfix/virtual.db and applies any changes made to /etc/postfix/virtual
Restarted Postfix:
Once the database is updated, restart Postfix to apply the changes:
sudo systemctl restart postfix

By not running the postmap command, my changes to the virtual file were not applied, causing the emails to be forwarded incorrectly.
